# Prevent hibernate from adding unique index to mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am not being to insert a duplicate entry in a table column due to MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolation Exception.

I have a following table structure:-

```
CREATE TABLE USER_ROLES (  
    USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,  
    ROLE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,  
    KEY USER (USER_ID),  
    KEY ROLE (ROLE_ID),  
    CONSTRAINT pk_user_roles PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID, ROLE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_user_roles FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
    CONSTRAINT fk_roles_user_roles FOREIGN KEY (ROLE_ID) REFERENCES ROLES (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have following 2 rows in the above table.

[image: USER_ROLES]

Right after table creation and insetion of 2 rows the indexes on the table are as:-

```
show index from user_roles;
```

[image: USER_ROLES indexes before]

At this stage following insert statement works with addition of 3rd row to table.

```
insert into user_roles values (1, 2);
```

Same insert fails when done through hibernate.
I have a spring mvc application that has User.java and Role.java domain classes with following mappings.

```
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
        @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",  
        joinColumns        = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},  
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}  
        )  
        private Set<Role> roles;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLES")
public class Role {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
        @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",   
        joinColumns        = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},  
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}  
        )  
        private Set<User> users;
}
```

When i start up my spring mvc application and then query the database for indexes on the table, it gives following output:-

```
show index from user_roles;
```

[image: USER_ROLES indexes after]

Above insert query (insert into user_roles values (1, 2)) when executed through application fails now with error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'UK_5q4rc4fh1on6567qk69uesvyf'
```

I wan't to be able to add duplicate entries in the USER_ID and ROLE_ID columns.
Please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve probably you are willing to have duplicated entries in to `USER_ROLES` that is: the same user may have more than one role associated. In that case you should use a many to many relation and not the one to many.

Comment: Thanks Paizo. Yes, that is exactly what i wish to achieve; An user can have multiple roles. I tried with many-to-many relation and it's working as expected.  Please post the comments as an answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: already taken by someone else XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe @OneToMany should be @ManyToMany since you want to allow multiple users with multiple roles and vice versa.

(You will need to remove the unique indices manually before hibernate updates schema)

Comment: Excellent! Good to hear.